# Synonyms for colour green

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, colors

I was wondering if there are any adjectives for describing the "sinister green" colour? The kind of gloomy green that looks like this

Source: [WallPaperUp](http://www.wallpaperup.com/29507/art_fantasy_dark_horror_landscapes.html)
[image: a science fantasy scene depicting a desolated bilious landscape]

Comment: There are a lot of variations of green in there but I'd say on average it's about #3f5910

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime Thanks. I'd like to know how would you call the general feeling of green in this pic? I'd call it bleak, sinister, horrific. But is there a special word for the "horrific green"?

Comment: I wonder whether it's really the colour that is sinister, or whether it's the gestalt of the creepy face, barren landscape, monochrome colour scheme, etc.

Comment: Maybe it’s a *poisonous green*

Comment: Trinny and Susannah call it "Disgusting Acid Lime Green" - if that helps. :)

Comment: @Davo I like that!

Comment: Not confined to green, but I'd use 'lurid green' here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would describe the feeling of the word using a noun modifier.  The words **nephrite** and **absinthe** seem appropriate.  *Absinthe* has the added benefit of implying not only color but possibly a feeling of unreality or intoxication.

> He walked through an *absinthe* haze.

*Nephrite*:

[image: jade ball]

*Absinthe*:

[image: two short tumbler glasses half filled with absinthe]

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what was I looking for. You are such a legend, RaceYouAnytime. Thank you so much, and for the helpful answers you provided for my other questions.

Comment: @AssenRobin always happy to help, good luck in your writing

Comment: I like the evocative nature of these suggestions, but I think you would need to add *-colo(u)red* or *-tinted* or similar to *absinthe* or risk your reader thinking you meant that whoever is walking is drunk on absinthe or that the room is filled with literal absinthe fumes.